# Show continuity of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Show that $f(x) = x^2+4x+3$ is continuous by using the $\epsilon - \delta$ method.

This is what i have now :

$\vert x_0 - x \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert x_0^2 +4x_0 -(x^2+4x)\vert < \epsilon $

$\Rightarrow \vert (x_0-x)(x_0+x)+4x_0-4x \vert < \epsilon$

$\Rightarrow \vert\delta(x_0+x)+4x_0-4x \vert < \epsilon$

So how do i define delta?

Like $\delta < \vert\frac{\epsilon-4x_0+4x}{(x_0+x)}\vert$ ?

I thought that $\delta$ should be defined without $x_0$. So that i can show the function is continous everywhere.

Comment: It is ok for $\delta$ to depend on $x_0$. You show that it is continuous at $x_0$, and that it will work for any $x_0$. If you want $\delta$ to not depend on $x_0$, then you are proving [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) which is stronger (and does not hold in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @angryavian, it is okay for $\delta$ to depend on $x_0$ since you are not proving uniform continuity, however it is not okay for $\delta$ to depend on $x$. Continuing your work from the middle:

\begin{align*}
\implies |(x_0-x)(x_0+x)+4x_0-4x|<\epsilon\\
\implies |(x_0-x)(x_0+x)+4(x_0-x)|<\epsilon\\
\implies |(x_0-x)[(x_0+x)+4]|<\epsilon\\
\implies \delta|x_0+x+4|<\epsilon\\
\end{align*}

What is the largest $|x_0+x+4|$ can be, based only on $x_0$ and $\delta$, not on $x$? Call this number $M$, and then let $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{M}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in steps, which would be easier:

1. Show that the sum of two continuous functions is continuous.
2. Show that the product of two continuous functions is continuous.
3. Show that constant is continuous.
4. Show that $x^n$ is continuous for every $n$.
5. Combine the above